# What is the meaning of '~' and '.' inside the function map?

Tags: r, anonymous-function

What is the meaning of '~' and '.' inside the function map?

Example:

```
map(dataset1[vector_input], ~ summary(., quantile.type = 5))
```

Comment: Have you read the online doc?  What parts of it were unclear?

Comment: `~` defines an anonymous function, with `.` being the placeholder for the argument, in the same way that `function(x) x` works.

Answer (score 3):

The tilda (`~`) is a decorator that simply means that whatever follows it is a formula. In the case of `map()` (and most other purrr functions), we see it simply means that whatever follows it will be applied to each element of the first argument of the `map()` function.

#### Example

Here are some simple but instructive examples from the `?map` docs:

```r
# You can also use an anonymous function
1:10 %>%
  map(function(x) rnorm(10, x))

# Or a formula
1:10 %>%
  map(~ rnorm(10, .x))
```

Note that these approaches are identical, except the second approach is a little more elegant, hence why you may like to use the `~`.

---

#### Background

More from `?map`:

> **.x**  A list or atomic vector.
>
> **.f**  A function, formula, or vector (not necessarily atomic).
>
> If a function, it is used as is.
>
> If a formula, e.g. `~ .x + 2`, it is converted to a function. There are three ways to refer to the arguments:
>
> For a single argument function, use .
>
> For a two argument function, use .x and .y
>
> For more arguments, use ..1, ..2, ..3 etc

Answer (score 2):

The `~` is a shorthand notation for an anonymous (*lambda*) function and arguments. Inside `tidyverse` the anonymous argument can be written as `.x`, `.y`
Consider the following cases, and compare their output:

```
map(1:5, ~ .x + 1) # default
map(1:5, ~ . + 1) 
map(1:5, ~ ..1 + 1) # same as .
map(1:5, ~ ... + 1) # careful with this
map(1:5, function(x) x + 1)
map(1:5, `+`, 1)

one = 1
map(1:5, ~ .x + !!one)
```

All evaluate to a list of length 5, with values 2 to 6.

However, when the anonymous function is not formatted properly, an error is thrown, here specifically because `z` (or `.z`) is not one of `.x` or `.y`.

```
map(1:5, ~ z + 1)
#> Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'z' not found
```

Some functions have more than one placeholder, such as `map2`. The `?map` help page tells us that for the second placeholder we can write `.y`.

```
map2(1:5, 5:1, ~ .x * .y)
```

`map` relies on `as_mapper` which in turn calls `rlang::as_function`. To see what your function is turned into (helpful for debugging), use `rlang::as_function(<your (anonymous?) function>).`

Note that use of non-standard evaluation inside anonymous functions should be handled with care, as internal handling of arguments may conflict with the forced evaluation. Case in point:

```
y = 1:10

# these results can be confusing
map(1:5, ~ .x + !!y)
map(1:5, ~x + !!!y

# but this works
map(1:5, ~ .x + {{ y }})

# see the following for why:
rlang::qq_show(map(x, !!y)
#> map(x, <int: 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, ...>)
rlang::qq_show(map(x, !!!y))
#> map(x, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L)
rlang::qq_show(map(x, {{ y }})
#> map(x, ^<int: 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, ...>)
```